# Show that if λ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with associated eigenvector $v$, then 1/λ is an eigenvalue of $A^{−1}$ with associated eigenvector $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question:

Let $A$ be an $n×n$ invertible matrix. Show that if λ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with associated eigenvector $v$, then $\frac{1}{λ}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ with associated eigenvector $v$. *Hint: * Consider $Av=λv$ and multiply by $A^{-1}$.

I multiply the problem out -

$Av=λv$

$A^{-1}(Av)=A^{-1}(λv)$

$v=λA^{-1}v$

I'm not sure what I do once I get here.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Divide both sides by $\lambda$.

Comment: Try dividing both sides of your last equation by $\lambda$.

Comment: It's worth noting (understanding) that if $A$ is invertible, then $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @Bernard okay so you can't divide vectors by a scalar so you take 1/λ and multiply v by that on the left?

Comment: That's correct.  Remember that $\lambda$ is a scalar, not a vector, so (as long as $\lambda \neq 0$) you're free to divide by it.  If $a$ and $b$ are vectors with $a=b$ and $\lambda \neq 0$, then $\frac{1}{\lambda} a = \frac{1}{\lambda}b$.

Comment: Yes. Dividing by $\lambda$ means multiplying by $1/ \lambda$.

Comment: @RobertShore  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Actually Division is usually defined as multiplication with the inverse in the context of a field.

Answer (score -1):

Care needs to be taken not to assume the result you are trying to prove is already true.

Let λ be an eigenvalue of the $n×n$ invertible matrix $A$ and $v$ be the associated eigenvector.

Let $λ^*$ be an eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$ and $v^*$ be the associated eigenvector.

Then,
$$(A-λI)v=0$$
$$Av-λv=0$$
$$Av=λv$$
$$A^{-1}Av=A^{-1}λv$$
$$\frac{v}{λ}=A^{-1}v$$
$$A^{-1}v=\frac{1}{λ} v$$
Also,
$$(A^{-1}-λ^{*}I)v^{*}=0$$
$$A^{-1}v^{*}-λ^{*}v^{*}=0$$
$$A^{-1}v^{*}=λ^{*}v^{*}$$
The only way these two results can both be true, as they must be, is if, $$v^{*}=v$$
and
$$λ^{*}=\frac{1}{λ}$$

Intuitively, when a square matrix acts on an eigenvector, the action essentially results in a scaling of the eigenvector. On a random vector there would also be rotation but not on the eigenvector. The amount by which the eigenvector is stretched or compressed is the eigenvalue, λ. So, to undo this action the scaling is $\frac{1}{λ}$ along the same vector.

Comment: Any chance of explaining the down vote ?